# Variable assignment within a while loop

Tags: python, mysql

What would be the closest pattern to doing the above in python?

```
while (item=self.cursor.fetchone()):
    print item['id']
```

Basically, I'd like to get the result of a single database-row. What would be the most direct way to do this, or do I need to have some generic loop like `while 1`?

Comment: Python will add an assignment expression in Python 3.8. Before that, assignments were *always statements*. If you don't have that, then `item = cursor.fetchone(); while item: ....; item = cursor.fetchone()`

Comment: what's your DB engine?

Comment: As an aside, this was a highly controversial addition to the language. Apparently, the furor over PEP 572's adoption was so great that it was a main motivation behind Guido van Rossum stepping down as BDFL. https://lwn.net/Articles/759654/

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest good question, as some DB adaptor api's support direct iteration over the cursor to obtain results row-by-row.

Comment: It would be wise to add a respective DB engine name to a list of tags in your case

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest added in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a comprehensive section on [`MySQLCursor.fetchone()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) doc page:

> The following example shows two equivalent ways to process a query
>   result. The first uses `fetchone()` in a `while` loop, the second uses the
>   cursor as an iterator:

```
# Using a while loop
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print(row)
    row = cursor.fetchone()

# Using the cursor as iterator
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Got it -- thanks for this very clear example and the two options. The second option is pretty neat, I had never seen that style done before.